# Why Is my compiler giving me these errors after I've downloaded GTK?

Tags: c, gtk

I'm new to the GTK library and there's a problem with compilation when running the funning program:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

int main( int   argc,
          char *argv[] )
{
    GtkWidget *window;

    gtk_init (&argc, &argv);

    window = gtk_window_new (GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    gtk_widget_show  (window);

    gtk_main ();

    return 0;
}
```

I typed this in when compiling:

```
gcc practice.c -o practice `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-2.0`
```

and got the following errors:

```
gcc: error: `pkg-config: No such file or d
gcc: error: gtk+-2.0`: No such file or dir
gcc: error: unrecognized option '--cflags'
gcc: error: unrecognized option '--libs'
```

I'm not sure why this won't compile, because I downloaded GTK+  2.24.10 the official site and I even stored it in it's own file and created a path for it in the environmental variables `;C:\GTK STUFF\`

So what am I doing wrong because when I fist downloaded the MinGW and added the c compiler to my path, it worked like a charm, so what's the problem now? Am I supposed to download something extra or do I store it elsewhere. I've tried storing it in the C binary file, but got the same outcome and the official site only gives you the files to download, and not anything else specific i compiling- other than the commands to compile at the cmd.

Comment: It looks to me like you don't have a real shell. One that expands ` ` correctly.

Comment: Because the DOS command prompt doesn't support this kind of expansion, and because Windows doesn't have pkg-config. You will have to work out the proper command line options yourself.

Comment: @us2012 then why would the tutorial tell me to type in pkg-config?

Comment: @Kenny Because the tutorial is for people using gcc on Linux, not MinGW on Windows.

Comment: @us2012 Are you saying that if I were using a linux and I downloaded the exact same thing that it would compile properly without any trouble and I wouldn't need to worry about the pkconfig thing?

Comment: You would still have to install GTK, but yes. However, figuring out which compiler options you need for GTK on MinGW is probably going to take a shorter amount of time than installing Linux and getting used to it if you haven't used it before.

Comment: If you installed MSYS along with MinGW and ran it in an MSYS command prompt (i.e. bash shell) then it probably would work.